# jquery image preview before upload on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, filereader

I want to preview images before upload. It works fine on desktop but when i want to preview images on mobile, it rotates the images by itself. for example, even if my image is vertical, it turns image horizontal. And another problem is, post method is too slow on mobile. I need help. Sorry for my english. Thanks

Here is my code to preview images:

```
$("#uploadPhoto").on('change', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var countOfFiles = $this[0].files.length;
    var maxSize = countOfFiles * 5242880;
    if($this[0].files[0].size > maxSize)
    {
        $.smallBox({
            title : "Too large",
            color : "#c69120",
            iconSmall : "fa fa-warning fa-2x fadeInRight animated",
            timeout : 9000
        });
        $('#uploadPhoto').val('');
    }
    else
    {
        var url = (URL || webkit).createObjectURL($this[0].files[0]);
        var sonDiv="";
        var files = $this[0].files;
        var imgPath = $this[0].value;
        var extn = imgPath.substring(imgPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
        var image_holder = $("#image-holder");
        image_holder.empty();
        if (extn == "gif" || extn == "png" || extn == "jpg" || extn == "jpeg") {
            for (var i = 0; i < countOfFiles; i++)
            {
                var url = (URL || webkit).createObjectURL($this[0].files[i]);
                var f = files[i];
                storedPhotos.push(f);
                rotateValues.push({
                    filename:f.name,
                    rotate:0
                });

                var spanDiv = "<div class='col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 no-padding tempFile'><span data-id='" + f.name + "' data-value='0' class='close rotate pull-left'><i class='fa fa-repeat'></i></span><span class='close closethis'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></span>";
                var imageDiv = "<img class='img-responsive ' data-id='" + f.name + "' src='" + url + "'/></div>";
                sonDiv += spanDiv + imageDiv +'</div>';
            }
            $(sonDiv).appendTo(image_holder);
            sonDiv="";
        } else {
            alert("Only Image Files!");
        }
    }

});
```

and this is my post method:

```
  $("form#formPost").submit(function (event) {
    var bad=0;
    var $this = $(this);
    var $currentItem;
    var items = $('#formPost :input');
    for (var i = 0, j = items.length; i < j; i++) {
        $currentItem = $(items[i]);
        if( $.trim($currentItem.val()) != "" )
            bad++;

    }

    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($this[0]);
    for (var i = 0; i < storedPhotos.length; i++) {
        formData.append('uploadPhoto2', storedPhotos[i]);
        bad++;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < storedFiles.length; i++) {
        formData.append('uploadFile2', storedFiles[i]);
        bad++;
    }


    if (bad> 1)
    {

        jQuery.each(rotateValues, function(key, value) {
            formData.append(value.filename, value.rotate);
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Group/Post',
            type: 'POST',
            data:formData,
                async: true,
                cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (returndata) {
                storedPhotos = [];
                storedFiles = [];
                rotateValues=[];
                rotateValue =0;
                pageSize = pageSize+1;
                $('#image-holder').empty();
                $('#file-holder').empty();
                $('#Message').val('');
                $('#uploadPhoto').val('');
                $('#uploadFile').val('');

            },
            error: function (ex) {
                $.smallBox({
                    title : "Error",
                    color : "#c46a69",
                    iconSmall : "fa fa-close fa-2x fadeInRight animated",
                    timeout : 4000
                });
            }
        });
    }

    return false;
});
```

Comment: mobile devices are bad devices for web so there is nothing you can do to speed up the upload, however you could try reversing the process of how you handle file uploads

Comment: but what about rotating problem on mobile? how can i solve it? @ImmortalDude

Comment: Try showing a preview to the user first then upload the file to the server,  it may work

Comment: also as an additional note try using stock jQuery code

Comment: ok try using stock jQuery code rather than a plugin

Comment: i already show a preview to user. my main problem is when i take a photo with phone, it rotates the image by itself. when i take a portrait photo, it makes the photo landscape by itself. i don't want it.

Comment: have you tried on another phone? coz a few years back my android application had the same problem, turned out it was my sensor that was screwed

Comment: i really feel desperate right now. yes i tried on another phone and still got the problem :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141949/discussion-between-immortal-dude-and-user3188649).